# DataAdapter.Update() does not update data in DB

Tags: c#, ado.net

I've got an assignment which requires me to update the northwind database,
I've done everything like the tutorials say as follows

I fill The `DataTable` Using The `DataAdapter.Fill(table)`.

I build the `Delete,Insert,Update` Commands using `CommangBuilder`

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStr, conn);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter); 
adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand(true);
adapter.Fill(employees_table);
```

I also set a primary key for the table:

```
DataColumn[] employees_keys = new DataColumn[2];
employees_keys[0] = employees.Columns["EmployeeID"];
employees_table.PrimaryKey = employees_keys;
```

Now I've attempted to delete and add a row:

```
// accepts an employee object and creates a new new row with the appropriate values for 
// an employee table row 
DataRow row = ConvertEmployeeToRow(employeeToAdd);
employee_table.Rows.Add(row);`
```

and deleting a row:

```
DataRow row = employees.Rows.Find(employeeToDismiss.ID);
employees.Rows.Remove(row);
```

I should also point out that I've attempted to use `row.SetAdded()` and `row.Delete()`

Anyway, at the end when I try to update the database

```
int k = employees_adapter.Update(employees_table);
```

on added rows sometimes k get valued, on remove never, and in either case nothing really gets updated at all in the database itself.

Any insight of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: as i understand it , the dataadapter as a property called AcceptChangeDuringUpdate,
adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate , its is by default set to true ,  the dataadapter dose not have an function called AcceptChanges() like DataTable , DataSet or DataRow , besides i think the problem is with the northwind database on witch i'm trying to invoke these changes on , it seems to update but change back after a minute or tow , maybe there is  some kind of mechanism there witch restores all the default values .

Comment: For insertion no need to get primary key because in north wind employee's key column identity specification is set to yes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `employee_table.AcceptChanges()` after the call to `Update()` to save the changes to the database.

Comment: as i understand it , the dataadapter as a property called AcceptChangeDuringUpdate,
adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate , its is by default set to true

Comment: You're right - I got DataAdapter and DataTable mixed up.  Sorry.

Comment: i just came across this problem again ,
i never knew that i should of call acceptchanges()

a bit long over do but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the `CommandBuilder` really makes an `Update` command for you, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText);
```

If the primary key info is missing it won't build the update command at all!

Comment: I had the same issue, everything seemed fine but the DB didn't reflect the changes. Turns out there was no UpdateCommand after using CommandBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I am little confuse here your SqlDataAdapter name is adapter and you are doing updation in employees_adapter.The steps are so simple to work with SqlDataAdapter just follow theses

**Step No 1:**

```
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStr, conn);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter); 
    DataTable employees_table= new DataTable ();
    adapter.Fill(employees_table);
```

**Step No 2:**

After you got the data in dataset start manipulation on it..

To insert :

```
 DataRow MyRow = employees_table.NewRow();
 //Now Fill data in MyRow
 employees_table.Tables[0].Rows.Add(MyRow);
 employees_table.AcceptChanges();
 adapter.Update(employees_table);
```

To Delete :

```
 /get only the rows you want
 DataRow[] result = employees_table.Select("ID ="+id); //id will be provided by you
 //Now do here data updation
 employees_table.AcceptChanges()
 adapter.Update(employees_table);
```

Like wise you can apply updation..But after doing any changes must call
table.AcceptChanges() and then'adapter.Update(employees_table)'

Comment: thanks i found out every thing i did was fine , accept marking the removed row as deleted ,and the fact that i built my app config using the data connection wizard witch led the connection to apply only for a copy of the Database file in my bin/debug folder witch all the updates where invoked on , 10x alot

Comment: @Syeda There is no `Delete(DataRow[])` method on `DataAdapter`